# Set default Detail View Controller when nothing is selected in iPad in Swift (in Split View Controller)?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

I want to know that how can I set an default Detail View Controller when nothing is selected in master view controller in iPad in Swift.

For example, if the app just load inside and user didn't select anything, the detail view controller will be `ViewControllerDefault`, if user select any of the rows in master view controller, the detail view controller will be `ViewControllerResult`. So how can I do that in Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Over a long time has been passed, I hope it helps someone.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
        //..
        let initialIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(initialIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetail", sender: initialIndexPath)
        }
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
            if sender!.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) {
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {

                    // Get row from selected row in tableview

                }
            } else if sender!.isKindOfClass(NSIndexPath) {
                let tableCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender as! NSIndexPath)
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(tableCell!)

                // Get row from sender, which is an NSIndexPath

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is very useful, except I only understand objective c. I bloody hate Apple for changing the language. Now, it means that half the community don't understand the other half!